# How to determine what is different in an Object compared to another?

Tags: vba, excel, powerpoint

I am working in PowerPoint, but the question is the same in Excel. I want to be able to differentiate between two Charts, but as far as I can see the Locals window looks pretty identical to me. `ChartType = xlColumnCluster`, `BarShape = xlBox` and a bunch of other little things like this all seem the same. But I'm not a computer, and I want to know if there is a way to actually have VBA check for me and list all the differences in properties from one Chart to the other. If I can find something different in the charts, I believe I can then code to look for those differences in a more streamlined manner.

Comment: VBA doesn't support "reflection" (which would include iterating over the various properties of an object) so this type of task would be pretty difficult.

Comment: the two charts have different names ... use the watch window or the locals window to explore the chart object properties

Comment: If you're trying to write general case code that will isolate the differences between any two charts of the same general type, you'll need to compare hundreds of different attributes. If you're just looking to isolate the differences between two specific charts, you might try saving images of them and then switching back and forth quickly to see if anything appears to move. That'll give you something to focus more closely on in the object model.

Comment: Very unfortunate to hear that Tim... Jsotola, my goal is to find the chart that has Percent formatting on the y-axis labels so that I can change my data from 0.98 format to 98% format, so the name wouldn't help me unless I set before hand. @SteveRindsberg If you read what I wrote to jsotola, I know before hand what the difference is but I haven't been able to find any way to check the formatting on the Y-axis, hence me wanting to find the differences on each chart hoping that this would pop-up somewhere in the locals. I just can't find this by hand. Do you know how to do this?

Comment: Hint: when struggling with PPT chart VBA, create a similar chart in Excel, then record a macro while you make the changes you want. Not perfect, but a far cry better than the non-existent macro recorder in PPT ;-)  Something like this will get you there:  ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).TickLabels.NumberFormat = "0.00%"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

" my goal is to find the chart that has Percent formatting on the y-axis labels"
This is what you said in the comments, but it's not what you asked for in the question.

This macro will search your active presentation for any chart that has an y-axis formatted to "0.0%" and tell you which slide, name, id, type.  Be careful that if the axis is formatted to "0.00%", this will not find it.
I haven't found a generic % to check formatting for.

```
Sub Test()
For Each sld In ActivePresentation.Slides
            For Each shp In sld.Shapes

                If shp.HasChart Then
                  If shp.Chart.Axes(xlValue).TickLabels.NumberFormat = "0.0%" Then
                    message1 = "Name - " & shp.Name & " , Slide # - " & sld.SlideNumber & " , ID - " & shp.Id & " , type - " & shp.Type
                    MsgBox (message1)
                  End If

               End If

    Next shp
    Next sld
End Sub
```

Comment: Re generic % format, maybe:   If Instr(shp.Chart.Axes(xlValue).TickLabels.NumberFormat) > 0 Then  OR If Right$(shp.Chart.Axes(xlValue).TickLabels.NumberFormat,1)  = "%"